# xsl:for-each when expecting only one node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I encounter following problem with xsl:

I have following existing template that is used by other xsl files:

```
<xsl:template name="strength">
    <xsl:call-template name="show-strength">
        <xsl:with-param name="medStrengthUnit1"
                        select="epsos:numerator/@unit"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="medStrengthUnit2"
                        select="epsos:denominator/@unit"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="medStrengthValue1"
                        select="translate(epsos:numerator/@value, '.', ',')"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="medStrengthValue2"
                        select="translate(epsos:denominator/@value, '.', ',')"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="medStrength1"
                        select="epsos:numerator"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="medStrength2"
                        select="epsos:denominator"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Now I want to call this template, but I don't have the possibility to add a parameter to the method (since it is used by other stylesheets)

For now I used the following call:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$strength">
        <xsl:call-template name="strength"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

with strength being a param passed in from another method:

```
<xsl:with-param name="strength"
                select="epsos:quantity"/>
```

This is working, but I know there is only one strength, and I don't like it to use an xsl:for-each if I know already there has to be always EXACTLY 1 strength.

Is there a way to just call the template for the path, like:

```
//for ($strength)
<xsl:call-template name="strength"/>
```

Comment: It sounds like you need and want to change the context node to your `$strength` variable, for that you need `for-each` or `apply-templates`.

Comment: Are you sure you can't change the "strength" template? One possibility would be to give it a default parameter, like `<xsl:param name="strengthNode" select="." />`

Comment: Another possibility would be to add a `match` attribute to the template with `<xsl:template name="strength" match="foo">...</xsl:template>`, then you could use `<xsl:apply-templates select="$strength"/>` instead of the `for-each/call-template`. You would need to adapt the `match` to the type of element(s) you want to use the template with.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the template to accept a parameter rather than requiring the context item to be set. But you don't want to do that.

You can set the context item by calling xsl:for-each. But you don't want to do that.

You can copy-and-paste the code into a refactored template (or function) that doesn't require the context item to be set. But you don't want to do that.

So it looks like you're going to have to do something you don't want to do. Welcome to programming.